# How can I clear file size hidden app data of google drive API?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am using google `drive API` to Back-Up the `SQLite` file on my `AppFolder`. Its work fine. The problem is that on every backup the memory size has been increased. Initial backup file size was `1KB` but when I click on backup button, every time the file size of `AppFolder` of my app file has been increased.
How to check the file is exists or not on `AppFolder`?
                                                                                      If Exists then how to clear the memory of my app `AppFolder` file, then only back up my file on `AppFolder`. Please gave me some solution. I got stuck from 2 days to resolve this problem. But  I can't..

Where to add the search query to search the file and delete that file before uploading?
I have added the code. 
**Added Code:** 
Bakup Button Listener:

```
backupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                        .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
            }
        });
```

Then, in its callback,

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback = new
            ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();
                    new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                            FileInputStream inputStream = null;
                            File file = changeSQLiteToJSON();
                            try {
                                try {
                                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                                int bytesRead;
                                try {
                                    if (inputStream != null) {
                                        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                                            outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                file.delete();
                            }

                            MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                    .setTitle(JSON_NAME)
                                    .setMimeType("text/plain")
                                    .setStarred(true).build();

                            Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                                    .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
                                    .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
                        }
                    }.start();
                }

            };
```

FinalCallBack:

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
            ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Created a file with content: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for the file first deleting the old one after uploading the new one ?   https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries

Comment: @DaImTo Can you guide me where to add search query to search the file? I have added the code.

Comment: I am not an android dev so probably not the best person to ask.  Personally I would do it after you upload your file check if there is more then one delete the older ones.   Remember Drive treats files of the same name as different files.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for your help. I got the solution.

Comment: You should answer your question then you will then be able to accept it and get points.  With luck your answer will help someone someday.

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me::

Set false

```
boolean isUploading = false;
private static final String JSON_NAME = "yourfilename.txt";
```

BackupButton Listener

```
 backupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isUploading)
                    return;
                try {
                    isUploading = true;
                    Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(mGoogleApiClient)
                            .setResultCallback(fileCheckCallBack);
                } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {

                }
            }
        });
```

fileCheckCallBack for query the Metadata title from appfolder

```
 private ResultCallback<Status> fileCheckCallBack = new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
            }
            Query query = new Query.Builder()
                    .addFilter(Filters.contains(SearchableField.TITLE, JSON_NAME))
                    .build();
            Drive.DriveApi.query(mGoogleApiClient, query)
                    .setResultCallback(deleteMetaDataCallback);
        }
    };
```

deleteMetaDataCallback (Delete the file if it exists in app folder else create new file)

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult> deleteMetaDataCallback =
            new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Problem while retrieving results", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        isUploading = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    MetadataBuffer mdb = null;
                    mdb = result.getMetadataBuffer();
                    for (Metadata md : mdb) {
                        DriveId driveId = md.getDriveId();
                        String name = md.getTitle();
                        if (name.equals(JSON_NAME)) {
                            driveId.asDriveResource().delete(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(deleteSuccessCallBack);
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    if (mdb != null) mdb.close();
                    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                            .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);

                }
            };
```

After success full delete from app folder : deletesuccessCallBack

```
final ResultCallback<Status> deleteSuccessCallBack =
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                        isUploading = false;
                        return;
                    }
                    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                            .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
                }

            };
```

Then, in its driveContentsCallback

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback = new
            ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        isUploading = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();
                    new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                            FileInputStream inputStream = null;
                            File file = changeSQLiteToJSON();
                            try {
                                try {
                                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                                int bytesRead;
                                try {
                                    if (inputStream != null) {
                                        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                                            outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                                        }
                                    }
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                file.delete();
                            }
                            MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                    .setTitle(JSON_NAME)
                                    .setMimeType("text/plain")
                                    .setStarred(true).build();

                            Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                                    .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
                                    .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
                        }
                    }.start();
                }

            };
```

fileCallBack

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
            ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {
                    isUploading = false;
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Created a file with content: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
```